# Alterative array representation

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm facing a problem in C++ for which I currently don't have an elegant solution. I'm receiving data in the following format:

```
typedef struct {
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
}Data3D;

vector<Data3D> v; // the way data is received (can be modified)
```

But the functions that do the computations receive parameters like this:

```
Compute(int *x, int *y, int *z, unsigned nPoints)
{...}
```

Is there a way to modify the way data is received Data3D so that the memory representation would change from:

> XYZXYZXYZ

to

> XXXYYYZZZ

What I'm looking for is some way of populating a data structure in a similar way we populate an array but that has the representation above (XXXYYYZZZ). Any custom data structures are welcome.

So I want to write something like (in the above example):

```
v[0].x = 1
v[0].y = 2
v[0].y = 0

v[1].x = 6
v[1].y = 7
v[1].z = 5
```

and to have the memory representation below

> 1,6...2,7....0,5
>
> 1,6 is the beginning of the x array
>
> 2,7 is the beginning of the y array
>
> 0,5 is the beginning of the z array

I know that this can be solved by using a temporary array but I'm interested to know if there are other methods for doing this.

Thanks,

Iulian

**LATER EDIT:**

Since there are some solutions that change only the declaration of *Compute* function without changing its code - this should be taken into account also. See the answers related to the solution that involves using an iterator.

Comment: Do you have the possibility to change the Compute() function?

Comment: I cant see whats is wrong with the current method, surely you can call the function "Compute(&v.x, &v.y, &v.z, numPoints);"

Comment: It would be a solution but the code inside it is very very mathematical and any mistake can be deadly. Plus I might have structures with more than 3 members where I need to choose which member should be given. Imagine I have struct { x, y, z, t} and sometimes I need to give (x,y,z) to the function, otherwise (x,y,t) ... That's why I'm searching for a nice solution.

Comment: @CharlesB: Agree. Changing the Compute() function will make the program much more Object-Oriented.

Comment: @Eamonn McEvoy: &v.x is the address of an x element, but after it there is an y element, not the following x element.

Comment: Is copying the data an option, or is memory also something you need to look at.

Comment: Copying data would be an option but the algorithm is called *many* times and this can have impact on the performance.

Comment: @Iulian Şerbănoiu: anyway he could call `for (unsigned i = 0; i < numPoints; ++i) Compute(&v[i].x, &v[i].y, &v[i].z, 1);`.

Comment: @thkala They are arrays of nPoints elements

Comment: @Iulian Şerbănoiu: I'm afraid temp arrays have to be involved. At least it won't be hard to understand when other programmers read that part of code.

Comment: @Naszta: The algorithm needs arrays, not only 1 element unfortunatelly. The computation involves all the elements in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could of course change your computer function.
I assume that all operation done on your int* in compute are dereference and increment operation.

I did not test it but you could pass in a structure like this

```
struct IntIterator
{
    int* m_currentPos;
    IntIterator(int* startPos):m_currentPos(startPos){};

    IntIterator& operator++()
    {
        m_currentPos += 3;
        return *this;
    }

    IntIterator& operator++(int)
    {
        m_currentPos += 3;
        return *this;
    }

    int operator*()
    {
        return *m_currentPos;
    }

    int& operator[](const int index)
    {
        return m_currentPos[index*3];
    }
};
```

And initialize it with this

```
std::vector<Data3D> v;
IntIterator it(&v[0].x);
```

Now all you need to do is change the type of your compute function arguments and it should do it. If of course some pointer arithmetics are used than it is getting more complex.

Comment: It is very elegant, I will take into consideration

Comment: I added the operator[] and now I can use it quite well in my program. Thanks, I chose this as the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

### Iterator-based solution

An elegant solution would be to make Compute() accept iterators instead of pointers. The iterators you provide will have an adequate ++ operator (see `boost::iterator` for an easy way to build them)

```
Compute(MyIterator x, MyIterator y, MyIterator z);
```

There are normally very few changes to make to the function body, since `*x`, `x[i]` or `++x` will be handled by `MyIterator` to point to the right memory location.

### Quick'n Dirty solution

A less elegant but more straightforward solution is to hold your Data in the following struct

```
typedef struct {
  std::vector<int> x;
  std::vector<int> y;
  std::vector<int> z;
}DataArray3D;
```

When receiving the data fill your struct like

```
void Receive(const Data3D& data, DataArray3D& array)
{
  array.x.push_back(data.x);
  array.y.push_back(data.y);
  array.z.push_back(data.z);
}
```

and call Compute like this (Compute itself is unchanged)

```
Compute(&array.x[0], &array.y[0], &array.z[0]);
```

Comment: This. You won't escape transforming the data if you don't store it in 3 different arrays in the first place.

Comment: It's also my only choice for the moment.

Comment: @Julian added iterator-based solution to your problem, which has my preference :)

Comment: @CharlesB: your answer together with mkaes' answer could actually provide a extremely elegant and nice solution.

Comment: @Julian yep, @mkaes answer is exactly what I meant for iterator-based solution, but better detailed

Answer (score 2):

Reasonably elegant would be (not compiled/tested):

```
struct TempReprPoints
{
  TempReprPoints(size_t size)
  {
    x.reserve(size); y.reserve(size); z.reserve(size);
  }
  TempReprPoints(const vector<Data3D> &v) 
  { 
    x.reserve(v.size()); y.reserve(v.size()); z.reserve(v.size()); 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i ) push_back(v[i]);
  }
  void push_back(const Data3D& data)
  {
    x.push_back(data.x); y.push_back(data.y); z.push_back(data.z);
  }
  int* getX() { return &x[0]; }
  int* getY() { return &y[0]; }
  int* getZ() { return &z[0]; }
  size_t size() { return x.size(); }

  std::vector<int> x;
  std::vector<int> y;
  std::vector<int> z;
};
```

So you can fill it with a loop or even try to make the std::back_inserter work with it.

Comment: It's also my only choice for the moment.

Comment: One more constructor:

`TempReprPoints(const vector<Data3D> &v)
{
  x.reserve(v.size()); y.reserve(v.size()); z.reserve(v.size());
  for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i ) this->push_back(v[i]);
}`

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the syntax you want, you could use something like this.

```
struct Foo {
  vector<int> x;
    vector<int> y;
    vector<int> z;

    struct FooAccessor {
        FooAccessor(Foo & f, int i) : x(f.x[i]), y(f.y[i]), z(f.z[i]) {}
        int &x, &y, &z;
    };

    FooAccessor operator[](int i) {
        return FooAccessor(*this, i);
    }

};

int main() {
    Foo f;
    f.x.resize(10);
    f.y.resize(10);
    f.z.resize(10);

    f[0].x = 1;
    f[1].y = 2;
    f[2].z = 3;

    for (size_t p = 0; p < 10; ++p) {
            cout << f.x[p] << "," << f.y[p] << "," << f.z[p] << endl;
    }
}
```

I'd consider this an ugly solution - changing the way you access your data would likely be "better".